# Как определить последний ввод данных и вывести сначала s, потом списки p?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот код:

```
def r(a):
    global s
    p=[]
    k = len(a)//3
    if a[:k]==a[k:k*2]==a[k*2:]:
        p.append(a[:k])
    else:
        if a[:k]==a[k:k*2]:
            p.append(a[:k]+'*')
            s += 1
        elif a[:k]==a[k*2:]:
            p.append(a[:k]+'*')
            s += 1
        elif a[k*2:]==a[k:k*2]:
            p.append(a[k*2:]+'*')
            s += 1
    print(p)
    return s

def main():
    global h
    while True:
        try:
            t = input()
            r(t)
        except (ValueError, EOFError):
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s=0
    main()
```

И ввод данных в столбик:

- 181818
- 191818
- 181918
- 181819

Comment: Для начала нужно задать вопрос так, чтобы остальные поняли, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: @strawdog, на таких вопросах можно учиться работать с заказчиком :))) Лида перефразируй вопрос и приведи пример хотя бы

Answer (score 1):

Можно не печатать сразу результаты вычислений в функции, а вернуть из через `return` и потом уже напечатать в нужном порядке и формате в основном коде:

```
def r(a):
    # ...
    return s, p

s, p = r(t)
print(s)
print('\n'.join(p))
```

Comment: s, p = r(t)
NameError: name 't' is not defined   Что делать?

Comment: @Lida Ну это же кусочек программы, пример. У вас там понятно будет `t = input()` и остальной код который вокруг.

Comment: Это понятно, но если s, p = r(t) print(s) print('\n'.join(p)) вставить в функцию main, то не правильно срабатывает. А куда это s, p = r(t) print(s) print('\n'.join(p)) вставить